# Error message in Debian Stretch: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: debian, python3, gtk3

I'm using Pycharm IDE on the Linux Debian 9 stretch OS and getting the following error when I try to install the python Debugger extension (Cython).

The error I get is the following one:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

I think this is due to the fact that the OS didn't have the module/package suggested by the error message.

So I ran on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

and, alternatively, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

in the hope that the 32-bit version worked better than the 64-bit one (I run a 64-bit version).

Woefully, in the first case, I got that this package is already installed, while in the second one the terminal response stated that is not possible to find such package.

Moreover, the error comes out only when I run PyCharm from the terminal, not in other cases; by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

everything goes right and there are no error message in the terminal.

What is the package I need installing?

Comment: Please don’t use links as crutches, and don’t say “I tried _____” and then link to a question with four answers. Say what you tried and what happened.

Comment: Hi @G-Man! Thanks for commenting. I'm sorry for asking the question wrong; I edited the question in the hope to explain better my problem. Let me know whether you have other advices.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Answer (score 0):

The package you need to install is the development package.  The exact name may be depended on the version of your repository.  At present on Ubuntu 18.04 it is named: `libcanberra-gtk-dev`

You can use this command to list the names as well as which components you currently have installed (the command and output from my system):

```
$ apt search libcanberra-gtk | egrep ^libcanberra-gtk
libcanberra-gtk-common-dev/bionic,bionic,now 0.30-5ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
libcanberra-gtk-dev/bionic,now 0.30-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libcanberra-gtk-module/bionic,now 0.30-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcanberra-gtk0/bionic,now 0.30-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcanberra-gtk3-0/bionic,now 0.30-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcanberra-gtk3-dev/bionic 0.30-5ubuntu1 amd64
libcanberra-gtk3-module/bionic,now 0.30-5ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Installing the dev library will normally automatically install the other depends.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 , `libcanberra-gtk-module` is provided only by `libcanberra-gtk-module` or `libcanberra-gtk3-module`.

Comment: @GAD3R **libcanberra-gtk-module** is automatically installed in Ubuntu as part of the OS without any action from the user.  When you install `libcanberra-gtk-dev` the `libcanberra-gtk-module` is, as you can see in my answer **installed,automatic**.  There is a good chance, since `libcanberra-gtk-module` is already installed by default when during the Ubuntu installation, there are components from his `IDE` programming environment that is dependant on some components of the development package.  I don't believe `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module` will make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*
```

Comment: Could you please update your post to include more context to your answer? Simply format the command properly and state why you think this is the correct answer.